# Will using the iphone camera flash as a flashlight for long periods harm it in any way?

Tags: iphone, camera

We have an old iPhone 4 that we use as a music machine in a spare room.  Will using the flash as a nightlight overnight cause any damage?

My guess is no, but a part of me (maybe thinking of old camera flashes) thinks I should ask first.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't have technical answer for you however I personally would not leave it on for too long or extended periods of time muchness overnight.  If you need a nightlight then go buy one.  $3.96 at Walmart [Meridian Great Value 2-Pack LED Automatic Night Light, Soft White](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Meridian-10237-Meridian-Great-Value-2-Pack-LED-Automatic-Night-Light-Soft-White/26441070).

Comment: My concern would be battery running down.  But I guess you do this while plugged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no for two reasons,

1. The flash on an iPhone is an LED which unlike old camera flashes doesn't mind running for extended periods of time.
2. Flashlight use isn't limited by iOS. If the letting the flash run for a while would break the phone apple wouldn't allow you to do so or at the very least set a timer to turn it off after so long.

The only problem T could see is the bulb will eventually burn out, but considering you don't seem to need the camera anyway that probably isn't an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the lightbulb wires in a 4 have been know to short this has happened in my grandfathers phone but it took 3 years so it shouldn't be a big issue

Answer (score -1):

Ya led bulb should last years in theory. but they do fail sometimes. especially when left in hot environment (closed up car)